# Will quantum events ever occur on a macro-scale rather than a vacuum? Michio kaku says there's a chance we'll wake up on Mars tomorrow

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling, decoherence, coherence, quantum-teleportation

https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2018/10/beyond-weird-decoherence-quantum-weirdness-schrodingers-cat/573448/

In this post, it is shown that quantum decoherence in the macro world occurs almost instantly, except in vacuum and at low temperatures. Therefore, in the macro world, we cannot pass through walls. Nor can you suddenly wake up on Mars the next day. But Michio Kaku says that if we wait longer than our cosmic lifetimes, we could get through a wall one day or wake up on Mars the next day. Was Michiokaku right? Wrong? Is it possible that such events are possible because there is a possibility that our body does not interact with all other oxygen or photons and thus exhibits quantum coherence, just as there is a possibility that oxygen particles in a room only gather in the opposite direction? Will quantum events ever occur on a macro-scale rather than a vacuum?

Comment: How do you define possible for an event infinitly inprobable? Pick a random integer. There is a 0% chance you picked the number 13 yet its still possible.

Comment: The odds are not even as good as my hair growing back, and that's a bleak prospect I may tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waking up on Mars is impossible for any reasonable interpretation of impossible. However, macro-scale events that are prohibited in classical physics but predicted by QM, in environments far from vacuums, are commonplace. For example, the temperature predicted for the center of the sun is too low for molecular kinetic energy to overcome the coulomb potential keeping nuclei separate often enough to sustain stellar fusion unless quantum tunneling through potential barriers is accounted for. More close to home, modern computers (and hence practically every modern tool and appliance) depend on a QM picture of electron tunneling.

Comment: However, on Earth, decoherence occur almost instantly, so it is impossible for humans to perform quantum tunneling in an environment like Earth, isn't it?

Comment: @Nunes If you're asking if humans can tunnel like quanta, no; humans are not quanta but are made of something in the general neighborhood $10^{30}$ quanta. Finding them all in a classically prohibited region (tunneling) at once is something similar to rolling a billion billion trillion dice and having all of them come up 6. Finding them all in a classically prohibited region *in a configuration that's still recognizable as a human* is like rolling a billion billion trillion dice and having them all come up 6 while also spelling out the complete works of Shakespeare by how they land.

Comment: @Nunes On the other hand, if you're asking whether humans can set up experiments in which quanta will tunnel and humans will measure something as a result - yes, absolutely.

Comment: In either case, being on Earth or in deep space wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The rate of a tunneling event in which an object of your mass (or any human's mass) moves from Earth to Mars is not zero, but so small that by the time it has a reasonable chance to occur, you, Mars, the solar system, the galaxy, all visible light and known structures in the observable Universe, and the black holes those structures eventually and inevitably collapsed into, would long since have ceased to exist.

Comment: However, on Earth, decoherence occur almost instantly, so it is impossible for humans to perform quantum tunneling in an environment like Earth, isn't it? So isn't the probability 0 in earth?

Answer (score 0):

I will add that there are everyday examples of quantum effects on the macro scale here on earth. My favorite is the laser, where simulated emission is purely quantum but those emission events do not average out to zero; instead they add together and are blindingly obvious on the macro scale.

Comment: However, on Earth, decoherence occur almost instantly, so it is impossible for humans to perform quantum tunneling in an environment like Earth, isn't it? Isn't it possible only in an environment other than Earth for such a thing to happen to humans?